# How to set Lucene search engine significant frequency?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

**What is the best way to set Lucene Index file generation over significant frequency in Lucene.Net?**

I added Lucene.Net in my Poject, but the table modifying frequently like inserting new data or modifying the field which is used in Lucene index.

So at what frequency I regenerate Lucene index?

Comment: can you try to add some more details? like what you have done so far and how you thinking about it?

Comment: Hi @SaikatChakrabortty I edited my question can you please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to regenerate index? The most simple solution to me is:

1. create a table like `data_to_index (id of added/updated entity, added_timestamp, processed_timestamp)`
2. create an indexing background service; this service should read identifiers from this table and update existing lucene index.

It's expected to have some delay between the moment when data has been added/updated into the table and the moment when new data has been added to lucene index.